# Jquery Intercept Event on element insert after loading Dom

Tags: jquery

I have a problem, I can not intercept the events over a div that i insert after loading the DOM with jquery

This is the code that insert a new div in the dom

```
$("button#addnote").click(function (e) {
    //alert("add note click");
    $("#contenitorenote").append("<div class='nota'><a href='#' class='ciao'>X</a> <textarea  style='width:300px;height:200px;' id='note' placeholder='Inserisci Note'></textarea></div>");
});
```

This is the code that i use for intercept a click, but don't work

```
$("#contenitorenote").delegate( ".nota", "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("click remove");
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        alert("test remove");
        $(this).remove();


});
```

How is the right way ?

Thans

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vf6tg670/1/ - looks fine

Comment: Notice that `delegate` is not the prefered way though